# How to Fetch Invalid records of certain condition in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I Have 5 records with RecordID as below
RecordID
3@,
20,
20,
10,
20
i want to fetch only the records which have RecordID 10 followed by 20.
How to do this in SSIS.

Comment: Execute SQL Task. It would be great if you can show what you've tried or thought of atleast.

Comment: Please add versions you are using of SQL Server and SSIS. letting us know if you have ability for a lag() command. Do you have an identity key?

Comment: Are there any more records to be fetched after 10 and 20 say 30,40,50 etc?  Is there any business rule that determines the order or does it come in a list?

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a major assumption here (you have an ordered identity column)

--select the Record ID 10 row where followed by a record id 20 row.

```
select t1.*
from table t1
 join table t2 on t1.[Identitycolumn] = t2.[identityColumn]+1
where t1.recordID='10' and t2.RecordID='20' -- Looks like you have a string '3@'
```